# Find movement distance between two frames -- python

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I have a short video of a moving object. for some reason I need to estimate the object's movement distance between two specific frames. It is not necessary to be exact. 
Does anyone know how I can do this in python and opencv or any image processing library?
Thanks

Comment: movement of the object or of the image or of the camera?

Comment: @Micka movement of the object

Comment: do you know the location of the object in one of the images or in both?

Comment: @Micka I did frame sampling for my video. I have frame #30 and frame #35 I want to measure the movement distance between these two frames that I have them as two images

Comment: depending on the content you could use keypoint matching with a region of interest, optical flow, or one of the tracking methods provied by opencv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know in opencv, there is for sure something similar but you can easily do it with `scikit-image` module. I do it on a regular basis to align frames.

See this example here:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_register_translation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-transform-plot-register-translation-py

EDIT: I found something very similar in opencv here

https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/db/d61/group__reg.html